# Relational Algebra in SQL using variables?

Tags: mysql

How would I write this in SQL. Let's say I have a relation which is

college(name, age, address)

I want to find the names of the students that are 20

Is there a way I can write this in SQL

```
R1 = σ(age = 20) from college

R2 = π(name) from R1
```

I guess I can write this as

```
select name from college where age = 20;
```

Just wondering how I could use variables to make it cleaner?

Comment: Couldn't be any cleaner. Do you mean more flexible?

Comment: I actually find the ordinary SQL you've written both clearer and terser. The relational algebra formalism bears no relation (ha!) to how people think about data processing in the real world.

Comment: You couldn't/wouldn't

Comment: @steve Relational algebra reflects exactly "how people think". Operators are 1:1 with AND, OR, AND NOT, EXISTS, etc. Unfortunately this is not taught. Whatever sense one makes in SQL is a contortion of simpler thinking in relational algebra. [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: This post asks four questions, what is your question? Are your R1/R2 assignments supposed to be in RA (relational algebra)? Please give a reference to its definition, there are many versions of RA. What does "cleaner" mean? What did you learn from googling the MySQL manual for varialbles & assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding my comment on the question, if you really wanted to split a query into intermediate steps (which is relevant to anything but the most straightforward queries), you'd write it something like this:

```
WITH age_20_colleges AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM college 
    WHERE age = 20
)
SELECT name 
FROM age_20_colleges
```

This basically assigns a filtered set to a named table "variable" `age_20_colleges` (although in SQL this would not be called a "variable" in this context, it would be called a "derived table"), and then the final query selects `names` from this set.